# java multidimensional arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I just wrote this function to add values into Multidimensional arraylist, but dont get it why all added values overwrites into recent added value. I need to figure out why this happening. As javadoc says it has to act like this " Appends the specified element to the end of this list". And i dont see any place at his code, where previously added value could be overwriten . One more strange thing is that size of array increases

Here is my output:

`[0.4, 0.42, 0.4, 1.2200000000000002, 0.0010000000000000009]  after add 0
    [0.4, 0.42, 0.4, 1.2200000000000002, 0.0010000000000000009]  after add 1
    [0.4, 0.42, 0.4, 1.2200000000000002, 0.0010000000000000009]  after add 2
    [0.4, 0.42, 0.4, 1.2200000000000002, 0.0010000000000000009]  after add 3
    [0.4, 0.42, 0.4, 1.2200000000000002, 0.0010000000000000009]  after add 4
    [0.4, 0.42, 0.42, 1.24, 0.01200000000000001]  after add 0
    [0.4, 0.42, 0.42, 1.24, 0.01200000000000001]  after add 1
    [0.4, 0.42, 0.42, 1.24, 0.01200000000000001]  after add 2
    [0.4, 0.42, 0.42, 1.24, 0.01200000000000001]  after add 3
    [0.4, 0.42, 0.42, 1.24, 0.01200000000000001]  after add 4
    [0.4, 0.42, 0.42, 1.24, 0.01200000000000001]  after add 5
    [0.4, 0.44, 0.4, 1.2400000000000002, 0.011999999999999983]  after add 0
    [0.4, 0.44, 0.4, 1.2400000000000002, 0.011999999999999983]  after add 1
    [0.4, 0.44, 0.4, 1.2400000000000002, 0.011999999999999983]  after add 2
    [0.4, 0.44, 0.4, 1.2400000000000002, 0.011999999999999983]  after add 3
    [0.4, 0.44, 0.4, 1.2400000000000002, 0.011999999999999983]  after add 4
    [0.4, 0.44, 0.4, 1.2400000000000002, 0.011999999999999983]  after add 5
    [0.4, 0.44, 0.4, 1.2400000000000002, 0.011999999999999983]  after add 6`

And here is my function:

```
public void createArrayList(ArrayList<Double> list,ArrayList<Double>
listLaid,int size,double sum, double absValue){   
ArrayList<Double> workArray = new ArrayList<>();  
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>
workMatrix= new ArrayList<>();

double abs=0;
for(int a = 0; a < size ;a++){
     for(int b = 0; b < size ; b++){
           for (int c = 0 ; c < size; c++){

             abs =Math.abs(sum - list.get(a) - list.get(b) - list.get(c));
                 if( abs <= absValue){
                       double totalSum = listLaid.get(a) + listLaid.get(b) +                                            
                                         listLaid.get(c);
                       workArray.clear();
                       workArray.add(listLaid.get(a));
                       workArray.add(listLaid.get(b));
                       workArray.add(listLaid.get(c));
                       workArray.add(totalSum);
                       workArray.add(abs);

                       workMatrix.add(workArray);

                  }
              }
         } 
    }                   
} 
for (int i = 0; i < workMatrix.size(); i++)   
System.out.println(darbineMat.get(i)+"  after add  "+i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are always adding the same **instance** of a list to the list. That means that all rows of the final `workMatrix` are **identical**.

You have to create a new `ArrayList` for each new row. Replacing

```
workArray.clear();
```

with

```
workArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

should be sufficient here.

---

**EDIT**: The concept of "references" may be confusing at the first glance (and there are programming languages where this concept does not exist in the same way). But when you are creating an instance of a list like this

```
ArrayList<Double> workArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

then `workArray` is only a *reference* to the *instance* that you are creating. You could imagine this like a "handle" (and in fact, it's more like a "pointer" in C/C++, but this might become too confusing now). The key point is that when you write

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> workMatrix = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> workArray = new ArrayList<>();  
workMatrix.add(workArray);
```

then you only add the *reference* to the `workMatrix` list. This *reference* still refers to the one and only instance that you created:

```
// This prints "true": The first element of the matrix
// and the workArray are IDENTICAL. (Not only equal, 
// but really IDENTICAL)
System.out.println(workMatrix.get(0) == workArray);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! But still I dont get it why. It seems that I am clearing the old arraylist and adding new values from 0 index. I had tried removeAll() didnt work either

Comment: @user3661552 Added an EDIT. But these are rather basic concepts, and you can find many resources explaining this in more detail (and with some nice images) on the web.